# Select Case with Boolean Functions

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm building a JSON recursive descent parser and I'm confronted with a somewhat annoying situation.

It is often convenient to use Select Case statements to decide what needs to be parsed next, but occasionally the class of a character needs to be used as a criteria. **Is there a way to include boolean functions as a criteria in a Case statement?** *Or, phrased more generally, is it possible to include a boolean criteria in the Case statement independent of the comparison with the Select Case variable?*  I fear it's an all-or-nothing proposition where I'll have to change the beautifully succinct Select Case statements for a wordy sea of If_Then-ElseIf-Else-End_If's.

This works just fine:

```
Select Case curr_char
    Case "{"
        'Parse an Object
    Case "["
        'Parse an Array
    Case Else
        'Parser Error
End Select
```

But suppose I have a function `Private Function isAlpha(str As String) As Boolean`.  This doesn't work because the result of `IsAlpha`, `True`/`False`, is compared against the value of `curr_char`:

```
Select Case curr_char
    Case IsAlpha(curr_char)
        MsgBox "It's alpha!"
    Case "{"
        'Parse an Object
    Case "["
        'Parse an Array
    Case Else
        'Parser Error
End Select
```

In order to avoid changing the structure of the existing code, I used the ugly, hacky, kludgy:

```
Select Case True
    Case IsAlpha(curr_char)
        MsgBox "It's alpha!"
    Case curr_char = "{"
        'Parse an Object
    Case curr_char = "["
        'Parse an Array
    Case Else
        'Parser Error
End Select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with an intermediate function which evaluates `curr_char`, and base the `Select Case` on that function's return value.

```vb
Select Case Categorize(curr_char)
    Case "isAlpha = True"
        MsgBox "It's alpha!"
    Case "{"
        'Parse an Object
    Case "["
        'Parse an Array
    Case Else
        'Parser Error
End Select

Public Function Categorize(ByVal pChar As String) As String
    Dim strReturn As String

    If isAlpha(pChar) Then
        strReturn = "isAlpha = True"
    Else
        strReturn = pChar
    End If
    Categorize = strReturn
End Function
```

I think that satisfies the requirement you described, but not sure how much I like it.  So I won't be offended if you say "Yuck!".

However, this approach is extensible.  You could adapt `Categorize()` to handle an additional function, then extend the `Select Case`.

```vb
Case "SomeOtherFunction = True"
```

Comment: Cool! I like the idea, but for performance' sake I think I might just have Categorize return a CATEGORYENUM or something with the applicable character classes, ie ce_LeftBrace, ce_LeftBracket, ce_Alpha, ce_Numeric... etc. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Fair enough, I'll give it a few more hours and see what SO brings.  Gotta see if Sid has any comments :)

Comment: Since character classes won't overlap the way I'm using them, I have decided to go with a pregenerated array that maps an ascii/unicode code (the index) to a CharacterClassEnum.  I wrap the array mapping in a function as you've suggested to take care of edge cases.  Thanks again!